# gcm not supporte in RMSPushNotificationsBundle

Tags: notifications, bundle, push

i'm trying to send message with the RMSPushNotificationsBundle with gcm Android.
I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'OS type rms_push_notifications.os.android.gcm not supported'
```

It's about to add an handler, in the class Notifications when sending a message :

```
    $notifPush = new RMS\PushNotificationsBundle\Service\Notifications();
use RMS\PushNotificationsBundle\Message\AndroidMessage;
$message = new AndroidMessage();
$message->setMessage('oh it\s a new Week');
$message->setDeviceIdentifier('xxxxxxx');
$message->setGCM(true);
$notifPush->addHandler('android','gcm');
$notifPush->send($message);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using it with symfony as a bundle the handlers are added automatically if you've configured the os in the `config.yml` ([see docs](https://github.com/richsage/RMSPushNotificationsBundle#user-content-configuration)).

If not, there's a handler class for every OS; you need to instantiate, configure and add it.

Example:

```
$iosHandler = new \RMS\PushNotificationsBundle\Service\OS\AppleNotification(ADD_CONFIG_PARAMS_HERE);
$notifPush->addHandler('rms_push_notifications.os.ios', $iosHandler);
```